# Why is a set used instead of a map? C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

Sets are used to get information of an object by providing all the information, usually used to check if the data exists. A map is used to get the information of an object by using a key (single data). Correct me if I am wrong. Now the question is why would we need a set in the first place, can't we a map to see if the data exist? why would we need to provide all the information just to see if it exist?

Answer (score 2):

There are many operations where you just need a set. Using a map would be just extra space.

1. Set operations (Union, Intersection etc.).
2. Keeping unique elements from a collection of numbers, objects etc.

Comment: +1 This is the real issue I see. In many cases you don't need keys at all - why would you use a map?

Comment: correct. sets are particularly useful when the elements are smaller in size so inserting+sorting is fast. Also, using sets and maps are only good when the number of elements are small (small is relative here). You might find this lecture useful (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIHAEYyoTUc) where Alex says try to use arrays/vectors as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

A `set` serves to group items of the same `type` that are different among themselves (i.e., they are not `equal`). For example, the numbers `1` and `2` are both of `int` type, but `1!=2`.

`set` containers are useful when you want to keep track of collections of homogeneous things as a group, and perform mathematical operations on such groups (like intersection, union, difference, etc). For example, imagine a `set` of search results containing all the documents mentioning the words `cat` and `dog`. And then another `set` containing all the documents mentioning the words `pet`. The `union` of those two sets would give you the group of documents containing the words `cat`, `dog`, and `pet`. Notice that such group will have no repetitions (i.e., if a document was in the both sets initially, it will be only once in the second set).

`maps` are most certainly **not** a `set`, but they can be seen as an arrangement which allows you to associate a value with every element of a `set`. They are used to represent relationships. For example, the `set` of people working for a company have an associated `employee_number`; in this case a `map` would be a useful structure to represent such relationship.

Going back to the previous example, if you wanted to know how many times has each page been accessed, you could probably create a map along the lines of `std::map<Page, int>`, that is, a relationship between the pages, and the number of times each has been visited.

Notice that the keys of a map form a `set` (probably this is what confuses many people), and an implication of this property is that you can only have a given key **once** (there are some esoteric containers where a key can be mapped to different values though).

So, if you need to interact with groups and collections as a whole, and with the members of the group itself, probably you want a `set`. If you need to **associate** certain things with members of a group or a collection, probably you want a `map`. If the association spans more than one dimension, probably you want a `multi_map`.

**Important** notice that in C++ `std::set` and `std::map` are **ordered**. C++11 offers alternative **unordered** containers called `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 0):

A Set contains a unique list of ordered values, but a Map can contain a non unique set of unordered values accessed using a key.

Either could be used to determine if an object exists, it depends on your use case and how you need to be able to access that object - can you test to see if the Set contains an object that you have a reference to, or do you need to look it up by one or more keys to be able to compare it?

Comment: so a set is always ordered, and a map is always unordered?

Comment: A `std::set` contains a unique list of ordered values. A `std::multiset` can have duplicates, but the contained objects are still ordered. A `std::map` contains a set of unique ordered keys, and each key is associated with a value. A `std::multimap` can contain duplicate keys, but the keys are still ordered.

Comment: Incorrect - a `std::map` cannot contain duplicate keys, neither can `std::set`. `std::multimap` and `std::multiset` may contain multiples.  Have to vote down until corrected.

Comment: @NathanErnst you misread the answer.  The answer states that the values in a `map` can be non-unique, but says nothing about the uniqueness of the keys -- other than implicitly.

Comment: Given the wording, I stand by my downvote, until clarified, or an actual code example illustrating the intent.

Comment: Rereading again, I do stand corrected. Unfortunately, SO is not allowing me to reverse my downvote currently.

Comment: @FJam, to be explicit, a set is ordered by value. A map is ordered by KEY. The values are not ordered in a map.

Comment: sorry - answered from my cell and didn't word it that well, but you have hacked through to what I intended to say.